# Android ProGuard issues with Parse 1.3.5 jar

Tags: java, android, runtime, proguard, parse-platform

I am trying to build an Android app using Parse 1.3.5. In a previous version of the app I use Parse 1.1.3 without issues. In this version, it is all fine until I create a signed application package for release. Here I use Proguard and while the apk gets created, there are runtime errors like below:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No ParseClassName annoation provided on     class com.parse.ParseUser
at com.parse.ParseObject.registerSubclass(Unknown Source)
at com.parse.ParseObject.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
```

I already have the following the proguard.cfg. Not sure what else needs to be added. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
-libraryjars \libs\Parse-1.3.5.jar
-dontwarn com.parse.**
-keep class com.parse.** { *; }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved it by adding the below to the proguard configuration file to keep the annotation ParseClassName

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*
```